# Missing "Culture and Hostnames" menuItem in Umbraco contextmenu

Tags: permissions, umbraco7

After upgrading to Umbraco 7.1.5 I ran into a peculiar bug in Umbraco. I was not able to select the "Culture and Hostnames" menu-item from the context-menu anymore.

I tried to compare files but to no avail. We have several sites that run Umbraco 7.1.5, where this problem didn't arise. The userTypeDefaultPermissions for the admin in the UmbracoUserType table in the database were equal:
CADMOSKTPIURZ:5F7

Symptoms of the bug:
the "Culture and Hostnames" is simply missing or even worse - it might be there initially and then disappear after IIS-reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the permissions for a user the users default-permissions are fetched from the database as a string of chars; E.g. the admin users default-permissions are:
CADMOSKTPIURZ:5F7

Each letter will allow certain actions(IActions) to be allowed by the user.

The problem occurred because we had deployed the "Umbraco.Tests.dll" to the environment, which contained an IAction with the same permission-letter as the AssignDomain action ("ActionAssignDomain.cs"). This caused the "Cultures and Hostnames" menu-item to be removed from the resulting menu-item list.